# How to move an Azure Virtual Machine to another storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In Windows Azure, I have created a number of virtual machines over the same storage account. I want to move some of those virtual machines to a different storage account so that I can have Geo-Replication for only some of them instead of all.

Is there any way to change the storage account of a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Please find the refrences below-

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/22/migrate-azure-virtual-machines-between-storage-accounts/

http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/copying-vhds-blobs-between-storage-accounts/

Answer (score 7):

There is no such feature provided out of the box. What you can do is following:

1. Shut down the VM
2. Copy the system disk's VHD to the new storage account (use [Copy Blob feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx)!)
3. Create a new VM based on the copied VHD
4. (Pray that the new VM will boot up successfully :) )

Most of the times this scenario is valid and works.